# Android app crashes with weird error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have button that launches a ListActivity, but every time I click on it, the app crashes with the following LogCat error:

```
01-10 13:12:51.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 13:12:51.327: E/AndroidRuntime(2970): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.Settings}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

This is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dip" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewSettings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Java code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Settings extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("foo");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

I have already tried changing the list id to `list` but if I do this I get the following error:

```
If I do this I get the following error: `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/list').`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListActivity` does not require that you assign a layout to it via the `setContentView()` method, if you only want to show a ListView `ListActivity` contains by default a ListView.

In case you need to include more Views than a ListView in your `ListActivity` you can still assign a layout to your Activity. In this case your layout must contain a ListView with the `android:id` attribute set to `@android:id/list`.

So change your list id to:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: If I do this I get the following error: `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/list').`

Comment: @user1301428 android:id/list and not id/list

Answer (score 2):

This row in your XML:

```
android:id="@+id/listViewSettings"
```

...has to be like this:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Why? Well, the `ListActivity` requires you to use the id "`android.R.id.list`" if you want it to maintain your `ListView` (same thing applies when using a `ListFragment`).

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your xml `ListView-id`

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

In this case your layout must contain a `ListView` with the `android:id` attribute set to `@android:id/list`

Comment: @user1301428 Try using `@android:id/list`. Just Replace your `android:id="@+id/listViewSettings"` -->`android:id="@android:id/list"` inside your `ListView`